# Error looking up JNDI DataSource in tomcat 8.5

Tags: tomcat8, context.xml, server.xml

I am using `tomcat 8.5`, where war files are copied in webapps folder and are exploded. We have a app context files defined in `conf/Catalina/localhost/`. I have a context defined in `server.xml` like below
**server.xml**

```
<Host appBase="webapps" deployOnStartup="false" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context displayName="Application One" path="/app1" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

**app1.xml**

```
<Context displayName="Application One" path="/app1" swallowOutput="true">

    <Resource name="jdbc/APP1OS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            maxActive="100"
            maxIdle="10"
            maxWait="5000"
            maxAge="60000"
            username="username"
            password="password"
            url="jdbc:mysql://dbname:port/appint?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;socketTimeout=300000&amp;useSSL=false&amp;requireSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            validationQuery="Select '1'"/>      
</Context>
```

Then I get below issue:-

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error creating delegate data source for 'JNDI: java:comp/env/jdbc/APP1OS'
Error looking up JNDI DataSource (not found).
```

If I change my server.xml to add resource definition in context then it works fine.

```
<Host appBase="webapps" deployOnStartup="false" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
  <Context path="/app1" swallowOutput="true">
      Resource name="jdbc/APP1OS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="10"
        maxWait="5000"
        maxAge="60000"
        username="username"
        password="password"
        url="jdbc:mysql://dbname:port/appint?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;socketTimeout=300000&amp;useSSL=false&amp;requireSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        validationQuery="Select '1'"/>   
 </Context>

</Host>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? When you deploy the web app or when you access the data source in your web app?

Comment: during the server start, we create the datasource where it look for the jndi using jndi name, that's when i am seeing issue